# Making a header link in a custom Wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I have a site: www.31publishing.co.uk and want to link the header to the site, but not sure how to do it? The code for header.php is as follows:

Here is the php: http://codepad.org/ek2r2l0J

Answer (score 0):

you can add link in header by replace this code with

```
<div id="header" style="background: url(<?php echo $header_bg; ?>)">

<div class="inner"> 
    <div id="title_box">
    <?php if (get_option('op_logo_on') == 'on') { ?>

        <a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>">
            <?php $logo = (get_option('op_logo') <> '') ? get_option('op_logo') : get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png'; ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="Logo" id="logo"/>
        </a>

     <?php } else { ?>

        <a class="site_title" href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" rel="Home"><h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1></a>

    <?php } ?>  
    </div>
```

with below code

```
<a href="www.softwaretestingawards.com"><div id="header" style="background: url(<?php echo $header_bg; ?>)">

<div class="inner"> 
    <div id="title_box">
    <?php if (get_option('op_logo_on') == 'on') { ?>

        <a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>">
            <?php $logo = (get_option('op_logo') <> '') ? get_option('op_logo') : get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/logo.png'; ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="Logo" id="logo"/>
        </a>

     <?php } else { ?>

        <a class="site_title" href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" rel="Home"><h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1></a>

    <?php } ?>  
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: hi i check your source code and found may issue with html if you can provide full new source of header.php i will edit it :)

Comment: here is new one http://codepad.org/9pbQxK4D copy and replace existing one hope you like this one :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "...want to link the header to the site"?

The code you posted is the header.php that is included in every page.

It already contains a link that load the home page of your site when you click your logo or site name.

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>">...</a>
```

Comment: Yeah but I want it to link to the header I have put there